# wget with wildcards in http downloads

Tags: wget

I need to download a file using wget, however I don't know exactly what the file name will be.

```
https://foo/bar.1234.tar.gz
```

According to the [man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-accept-wildcards-143), wget lets you turn off and on globbing when dealing with a ftp site, however I have a http url.

How can I use a wildcard while using a wget? I'm using gnu wget.

Things I've tried.

```
/usr/local/bin/wget -r "https://foo/bar.*.tar.gz" -P /tmp
```

**Update**

Using the -A causes all files ending in .tar.gz on the server to be downloaded.

```
/usr/local/bin/wget -r "https://foo/" -P /tmp -A "bar.*.tar.gz"
```

**Update**

From the answers, this is the syntax which eventually worked.

```
/usr/local/bin/wget -r -l1 -np "https://foo" -P /tmp -A "bar*.tar.gz"
```

Comment: This is not exactly what you're looking for but it's related: Curl has the ability to use basic wildcards, eg:
`curl "http://example.com/picture[1-10].jpg" -o "picture#1.jpg"`

Comment: One gotcha for me was the `-e robots=off` parameter to *not* obey robots.txt: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11124664/1097104

Comment: I found adding the flags `-nH` and `--cut-dirs=<number>` was also useful

Answer (score 94, accepted):

I think these switches will do what you want with `wget`:

```
   -A acclist --accept acclist
   -R rejlist --reject rejlist
       Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to 
       accept or reject. Note that if any of the wildcard characters, *, ?,
       [ or ], appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, it will be 
       treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.

   --accept-regex urlregex
   --reject-regex urlregex
       Specify a regular expression to accept or reject the complete URL.
```

#### Example

```
$ wget -r --no-parent -A 'bar.*.tar.gz' http://url/dir/
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What happens if you have page with this: `<td><a href="10yard.zip">10yard.zip</a> (<a href="10yard.zip/">View Contents</a>)</td>`. How can you download only the 10yard.zip? I'm using `wget -r -np -nc -l 1 -A zip https://archive.org/download/mame-merged/mame-merged/` and it downloads the zip file, delete the file downloaded, and create a folder named 10yard.zip. Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel - If you have a new Q it's best to ask on the main site. It's OK if the Q extends/builds off of existing ones.

Comment: Like the one I asked yesterday: https://superuser.com/questions/1702157/download-10yard-zip-with-wget-not-10yard-zip

Answer (score 18):

There's a good reason that this can't work directly with HTTP, and that's that an URL *is not* a file path, although the use of `/` as a delimiter can make it look like one, and they do sometimes correspond.<sup>1</sup>

Conventionally (or, historically), web servers often do mirror directory hierarchies (for some -- e.g., Apache -- this is sort of integral) and even provide directory indexes much like a filesystem.  However, nothing about the HTTP protocol requires this.

This is significant, because if you want to apply a glob on say, everything which is a subpath of `http://foo/bar/`, unless the server provides some mechanism to provide you with such (e.g. the aforementioned index), there's nothing to apply it the glob *to*.  **There is no filesystem there to search.**  For example, just because you know there are pages `http://foo/bar/one.html` and `http://foo/bar/two.html` does not mean you can get a list of files and subdirectories via `http://foo/bar/`.  It would be completely within protocol for the server to return 404 for that.  Or it could return a list of files.  Or it could send you a nice jpg picture.  Etc.

So there is no standard here that `wget` can exploit.  AFAICT, wget works to mirror a path hierarchy *by actively examining links in each page*.  In other words, if you recursively mirror `http://foo/bar/index.html` it downloads `index.html` and then extracts links that are a subpath of that.<sup>2</sup>   The `-A` switch is simply a filter that is applied in this process.

In short, if you know these files are indexed somewhere, you can start with that using `-A`.  If not, then you are out of luck.

---

<sup>1. Of course an FTP URL is an URL too.  However, while I don't know much about the FTP protocol, I'd guess based on it's nature that it may be of a form which allows for transparent globbing.</sup>

<sup>2. This means that there could be a valid URL `http://foo/bar/alt/whatever/stuff/` that *will not be included* because it is not in any way linked to anything in the set of things linked to `http://foo/bar/index.html`.  Unlike filesystems, web servers are not obliged to make the layout of their content transparent, nor do they need to do it in an intuitively obvious way.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Use option -nd to save all files to the current directory, without hierarchy of directories, example:

```
wget -r -nd --no-parent -A 'bar.*.tar.gz' http://url/dir/
```

Answer (score 1):

The above '-A pattern' solution may not work with some web pages. This is my work-around, with a double wget:

1. `wget` the page
2. `grep` for pattern
3. `wget` the file(s)

Example: suppose it's a news podcast page, and I want 5 mp3 files from top of the page:

```
wget -nv -O- https://example/page/ |
 grep -o '[^"[:space:]]*://[^"[:space:]]*pattern[^"[:space:]]*\.mp3' |
  head -n5 | while read x; do
    sleep $(($RANDOM % 5 + 5))  ## to appear gentle and polite
    wget -nv "$x"
  done
```

The `grep` is looking for double-quoted no-space links that contain `://` and my file name `pattern`.

Comment: what is RANDOM here ?

Comment: A shell variable, see `bash` man page.
RANDOM Each time this parameter is referenced, a random integer between 0 and 32767 is generated.